# Formula to move/shift items in a 2d-table, so that they are in same rows of the matching 1d-table items?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table Google Sheet with more than 100 rows and columns. Each column is alphabetically sorted, The key table/column contains all the unique items in the table (also sorted alphabetically). Each item in the table has a unique URL attached to it (col1 item A has a different URL from col2 item A).
Note: key table/column items have no URLs attached

I need to move these items to the matching **key table item** rows, while keeping their columns are unchanged. Is there a way to do this using a single Gsheet formula (or 2, a easier way). The changes don't need to be done on the table itself.

[current and required table formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKNeG.png)

```html
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
</style>

<h3>Current Table</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>col 4</th>
    <th>col N</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>A</B>
    </td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>B</B>
    </td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>C</B>
    </td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>D</B>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>E</B>
    </td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>F</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>G</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>H</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<h3>Required Table</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Key</th>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
    <th>col 3</th>
    <th>col 4</th>
    <th>col N</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>A</B>
    </td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>B</B>
    </td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>C</B>
    </td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>D</B>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>E</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>F</B>
    </td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>G</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <B>H</B>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can probably help if you share a sample spreadsheet. similar to what you shared a screenshot of

Comment: @MattKing you can run the code snippet and copy the table generated table (drag and copy) and paste it on the sheet

Comment: @MattKing here is the link for a viewable sample https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bX23IkBWTE5ZfcaybnzkIQBLzJOFMRb5y9N2jMjxanc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, it looks like @kishkin did something similar to what I would have done, but I'd encourage you to read about the XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/  Maybe start a little further upstream with your question?  there might be a more efficient way to get at the real goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(
    VLOOKUP(
      (ROW(H3:H10) - ROW(H3)) * COLUMNS(B3:F10) + (COLUMN(I3:M3) - COLUMN(I3)),
      {
        FLATTEN(
          IF(
            B3:F10 = "",
              "",
                (
                    VLOOKUP(
                      B3:F10,
                      {A3:A10, ROW(A3:A10)},
                      2,
                      0
                    )
                  - ROW(A3)
                )
              * COLUMNS(B3:F10)
              + COLUMN(B3:F10)
              - COLUMN(B3)
          )
        ),
        FLATTEN(B3:F10)
      },
      2,
      0
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It should be mentioned that FLATTEN() is an undocumented function discovered recently by a user (March 2020).  It's believed it is intended to remain "hidden" in the back end of the sheets programming, but there is no guarantee that the formula will continue to work indefinitely.

Comment: And @MattKing should be thanked for showing me that function. Thanks, Matt! :)

Comment: @kishkin I'm getting a Formula Pass Error when I try this formula, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bX23IkBWTE5ZfcaybnzkIQBLzJOFMRb5y9N2jMjxanc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DilepDev please try again. I changed semi-colons and back-slashes (used if Russian locale is set) to commas (for English locale).

Answer (score 1):

According your snippet you can use following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B$9,$A13:$A20),$A13:$A20,""))
```

[image]

Comment: this formula is for one column, also it doesn't retain the links attached to the elements